# Symfony is not loading controller correctly: Fatal Error: Call to a member function addResource()

Tags: php, symfony

I am playing with DDD in Symfony2, I have added the following controller:
`\src\Coredomain\Companies\RestBundle\Controller\CompanyController.php`

```
namespace Coredomain\Companies\RestBundle\Controller;

use [...] ;

class CompanyController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

As for the route, I have in my main routing.yml:

```
coredomain_companies_rest:
    resource: "@CoredomainCompaniesRestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

And in `\src\Coredomain\Companies\RestBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml`:

```
coredomain_companies_rest_company:
    resource: "@CoredomainCompaniesRestBundle/Controller/CompanyController.php"
```

Now when I browse to any page or run `php app/console debug:router` I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addResource() on a non-object in /vagrant/coredomain/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/PhpFileLoader.php on line 45
[2015-06-09 12:03:32] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Call to a member function addResource() on a non-object {"type":1,"file":"/vagrant/coredomain/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/PhpFileLoader.php","line":45,"level":-1,"stack":[]}
```

When I checked `PhpFileLoader.php:45` I see:

```
44| $collection = self::includeFile($path, $this);
45| $collection->addResource(new FileResource($path));
```

I checked the `$path` var and it contains:

```
\vagrant\coredomain\src\Coredomain\Companies\RestBundle\Controller\CompanyController.php
```

Then I checked `$collection`, and it contains `int(1)`. So it turns out that `self::includeFile($path, $this)` returns 1 instead of an object. The method looks like this:

```
private static function includeFile($file, PhpFileLoader $loader)
{
    return include $file;
}
```

So basically `include $path;` returns `1` or `true`. And that raises two questions for me. Because when I put a breakpoint there it seems that this is *not* run when I remove the route and use the sample controller that came with Symfony2. However, it does run when I add my route for my own controller.

So what could I be doing wrong that it runs this part of the code for my route? And why does this return 1? Is this PhpFileLoader not meant to be for classes but for flat PHP files?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with a more "classic" route ? Like this one : http://pastebin.com/hHt0A8Sh ?

Comment: I had to change "CompanyController:index" to "Company:index", but what gives? This fixes my problem. Why does this work? I am new to Symfony2 so I am also trying to determine if I should just use the "classic" route or figure out why my other route isn't working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes my bad !

```
coredomain_companies_rest_company:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: CoredomainCompaniesRestBundle:Company:index }
```

This is just how routing does work on Symfony. Explaining that in one answer would be quite long. The documentation is rather well explained on this matter : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html.

A `resource` is [a reference to another routing file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-include-external-resources) that need to be including in the actual one.

Also PHP `include` returns 1 if the included file doesn't return another specific value.

[From the PHP documentation :](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

and :

> It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it.